# Unable to access gmail contacts via gmail addon (oauth scopes included already)

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am trying to execute this in my addon and I get an error

> You do not have permission to call getContact [line: 37, function: addOnLogic, file: app]

`var contact = ContactsApp.getContact('john.doe@example.com');`

I've added the following scopes.

```
"oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts" ]
```

Permission :
[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 1):

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202503/you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-getcontacts), it was suggested to add [this scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#scriptv1).

```
"oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
```

for the `ContactsApp.getContacts()` to work.